# Converting Parallel ForEach into PLINQ to process list of Tasks

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, plinq

I am trying to load as many messages into a server fast as possible. I currently have this bit of code and to load 50000 messages to a MessagingServer it takes around 5 minutes. This is a list of tasks that have server name, queuename and the message to place on the queue.

```
  taskList.Add(new Task(() => PlaceMessageOnQueue(server, queueName, message)));
```

This is the current code that I have but I want to convert this to PLINQ as hopes to make this even faster.

```
_= Parallel.ForEach(task, new ParallelOptions()
{
MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount; //I have 4 Cores
},t => {
 t.Start();
 t.Wait();
Console.WriteLine(t.Status)
});
```

What I have so far but this isn't starting the tasks. This is the code below that I need help with.

```
var results = task.
.AsParallel()
.AsOrdered()
.WithDegreeofParallelism(Environment.ProcessorCount)
.ToList();
```

Comment: *"process messages into a server"* -- This description is a bit confusing. The messaging server will process the messages, not your code. Your code just sends the messages to the server. Btw it seems that sending a message is actually more work than processing it, which is odd to say the least.

Comment: `_= Parallel.ForEach(task,` -- probably it's `taskList` instead of `task`.

Comment: Could you include in the question the `PlaceMessageOnQueue` method?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I am looking to change the Parallel for Each into a PLINQ query that will start the tasks that is all.

Comment: You hope to make this even faster as well. Just switching from the `Parallel` to PLINQ won't do it.

Comment: `var results = task.` -- What is the type of the `results`? It doesn't seem that this PLINQ query can have any sensible results, unless the `PlaceMessageOnQueue` returns something else instead of `void`.

Answer (score 2):

You can approach this by consuming the messages in parallel and selecting the result of processing the message, as in this example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var messages = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => $"Message {i}");

    var results = messages
        .AsParallel()
        .AsOrdered()
        .WithDegreeOfParallelism(Environment.ProcessorCount)
        .Select(m => PlaceMessageOnQueue("FOO", "BAR", m))
        .ToList();
}
static bool PlaceMessageOnQueue(string server, string queue, string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Starting {server}/{queue}/{message}");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine($"Finished {server}/{queue}/{message}");

    return true; // E.g. representing success
}
```

Note there isn't a reason to believe this will be fundamentally faster than your last approach. You may wish to look at a producer/consumer pattern using [Channels](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/). In many use cases, channels outperform similar concurrency options in .NET.

Comment: HI Eric. The code for which you have is a Parallel for each. I want to convert it into PLINQ

Comment: @TerranceJackson: That's what I get for answering SO before my first coffee :-) Hope the update solves your problem.